# Free, reliable backup-tool for Windows/Linux

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, backup

What's a good portable backup-tool, for a bunch of Linux/Windows machines? It should only backup data-folders specified by the user, doesn't need to be full images of the system.

Ideally, the backup target could be a network share/linux server; what's important is that the clients run both Linux and Windows, and I'd like a single solution for all of them. Ah and it should work on x64 Win7 ;)

Is such a tool out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rsync is the best network backup you're going to find. Deltacopy is a nice Windows port, with a frontend, scheduling and email reporting.. It also has a Windows server. I've used it on Xp, 2003, 208 and Windows 7 without problems. For the Linux machines, you can just use native rsync.

Answer (score 3):

I use BackupPC - it's fantastic:

http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: BackupPC is great but I had some problems to access a Windows 7 share (from Debian Linux). I found that Windows Live ID Assistant was the problem (really weird but after uninstalling it, it works).

Answer (score 2):

[Unison file synchronizer](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is the best thing I found so far. It's like rsync, only better, because it supports two-way sync and profiles. It also seems more resistant than rsync to cross-platform issues like permissions and file names.

The only downside compared to rsync is speed. My 60 GB home directory, after a single day's work, can be backed up to a USB drive in about 2 minutes with rsync, about 10 minutes with Unison.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want something a little more user friendly you could try crashplan which does everything you ask and also allows you to do backups to a friends system over an internet connection and to their online backup system (the last bit requires a paid subscription)

Answer (score 1):

[rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/). Really stable and good.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used [Linbox Rescue Server](http://www.linbox.com/ucome.rvt/any/en/Produits/LRS). It can backup full images as well as selected data from multiples Windows and Linux systems. It runs on a dedicated Linux server connected on the same LAN as the target machines.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [ShadowProtect](http://www.storagecraft.com/shadow_protect_desktop.php) - It REALLY does fast backups of the system.